# This loop is infinite but it should not be - C

Tags: c, loops, vector, infinite

look at this:

```
 int find_grad(int * table, int * value)
    {
      int i = 0;

      while (find_max_value(table) >= value)
      {
        table[(find_max_position(table))] = 0;
        i++;
      }

    return i;
    }
```

This is a pretty simple function: it uses another function (that works for sure, i tested it) called "find_max_position" that iterates through a vector of integers to find the position of the max value. So if the vector is {1, 3, 19}, find_max_position returns an integer, in this case 1.

I need find_grad to find the "grade" of the value I entered. For example, if I call find_grad(table, 3) on a vector like this {0, 1, 5, 4, 3}, the function should return me 2, because 3 is the third bigger value (it starts from 0).
But when I call the function the loop becomes infinite. I thought that it could be because when I do "table[(find_max_position(table))] = 0;" I'm acting over a copy of the vector and not the vector itself, and when the loop restarts the bigger value it's always there. Maybe I explained the situation a bit bad but I think it's easy to understand reading the code. Can anybody help?

EDIT: I forgot this > find_max_value just returns an integer, the bigger value found on a vector of integers.

Comment: Post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please.

Comment: Is `find_max_value(table) >= value` really the correct comparison, given that `value` is an `int*`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would get a bunch of useful warnings (which you should then fix), if you enabled them for your compiler (`-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang*, for example).

Comment: Post the whole code here. It may be the case that the function that you are calling is causing the infinite loop!

Comment: This is the whole code of stats.c, it contains all the functions I use
https://ghostbin.com/paste/auxxh

Comment: With -Wall -Wetra, changing *value to value, i don't get any warnings but the loop is infinite.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje why? With that statement the bigger value is changed to 0, then the next time there will be another bigger value. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is you are comparing an integer with a pointer. You missed a `*` before `value`.

Correct code:

```
int find_grad(int * table, int * value)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (find_max_value(table) >= *value)
    {
        table[(find_max_position(table))] = 0;
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

You can do this even without using pointer. You just need to remove `*` before `value`.

```
int find_grad(int * table, int value)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (find_max_value(table) >= value)
    {
        table[(find_max_position(table))] = 0;
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I get segmentation fault but at least the loop ends

Comment: Please check where it's crashing ! I don't see anything to crash the program inside this function ! @MatteoDelSeppia

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi: Calling `find_grad(table, 3);` could be the cause, the function is expecting an `int *` not an `int`.

Comment: @AlterMann Possible ! Though i'm not sure actually ! But it would have been easier using an `int` instead of `* int`. I don't know why OP used pointer here !

Comment: Thank you guys you are awesome! I solved the problem, I removed all those unneeded pointers and now it works fine :)

Comment: @MatteoDelSeppia welcome ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are comparing pointers, or pointer and integer. Probably it is not what you really want.

Comment: Good to say that he needs to dereference the pointer `> = *value` or pass a plain `int` instead of a pointer to`int` if the function doesn't affect his value.

Comment: I removed the pointer to the integer but it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `int` and pointer. Just change the line `int find_grad(int * table, int * value)` to this `int find_grad(int * table, int value)`. This should work fine.